# I accidentally changed persmissions to /usr/local

Tags: permissions

I have been installing android studio, I download it from the homepage [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/).

I follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux), But I can't unzip the tar.gz file here, because I don't have permissions, and I did it with sudo:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/android-studio-2020.3.1.25-linux.tar.gz .
$ sudo tar -xvzf android-studio-2020.3.1.25-linux.tar.gz
```

and now I must do `sudo ls` when I don't need previously, or I can't use `docker-compose` because it's in /usr/local/bin

I don't know which permissions it has originally, and I don't know if I must only change the /usr/local ones or made some recursive action.

```
$ sudo ls -latr /usr/local
sudo ls -latr /usr/local/
total 44
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root 4096 ene  1  2010 android-studio
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 src
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 games
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 jun  8  2018 share
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 dic 23  2020 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 oct 27 12:06 bin
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 oct 29 10:23 lib
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 nov 15 16:47 ..
drwx------ 11 root root 4096 nov 15 17:11 .
```

Comment: Not clear if and how you changed the permissions in the first place. Not clear from your output that you cannot unzip the tar. In other words: the question is very unclear.

Comment: `drwx------ 11 root root 4096 nov 15 17:11 .` suggests you somehow removed group and other permissions on `/usr/local` itself (normally it should be `drwxr-xr-x`)

Comment: Ok, my computer is broken now, I will need some time to repair it. In the meantime, is it normal to change folder permissions if you unzip a compressed file into a directory?